# Align instanced objects on a particle system

Tags: particles

Is there a way to align or adjust the alignment of instanced objects on a particle system? For example, looking through the y-axis, the objects are slightly misaligned.

[image: looking through y-axis]

It gets worst if you look through the x-axis:

[image: looking through x-axis]

And this is my instanced object:

[image: instanced object]

it has an equal length on the x and y-axis.

Here's the blend file I use for testing:

[image]

EDIT:
I found the source of my "misalignment", I forgot that rotating the object would do that, so when I reverted the object and reset to all zeroes, it looks better now. ‍♀️

[image: aligned after resetting rotation]

Answer (score 4):

I have realised my mistake and here's the answer.

I rotated the object which caused the misalignment. So to get the desired effect I wanted, I "applied" the rotation by pressing Ctrl-A and selecting the rotation to make it zero again. then the instanced object aligned properly again.

[image: corrected image]

Here's the test file

[image]

Comment: A classic EBKAC error.